# alter map key when there is more than one maximun value on groovy clousure

Tags: groovy

I Have two maps:

```
def map = ['a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c':5]
def map2= ['a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c':4]
```

I want to take the maximum value of the map like this:

```
def newMap = map.max {it.value}
```

and my output is correct ('c':5), my problem is with the second map because there is more than one max value. On this case I want **to change the key** so I can know that there was more than one max value. I want my output to be:

```
def newMap2 = map2.max {it.value}
assert newMap2 == ['+than1': 4]
```

Can I alter the key of the map in this specific case using groovy functions?
Can I achieve this inside the max closure?

I do not want to alter the key if there isn't more than one max value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that `map.max(Closure cl)` returns `Map.Entry<String, Integer>` and not a map. So if you expect a map with a single key, you will have to create one from the result you get.

`Map.max(Closure cl)` searches for the maximum value and returns it. There is no variant that allows you to modify function behavior in case of two entries holding maximum value. According to docs:

> Selects an entry in the map having the maximum
>   calculated value as determined by the supplied closure.
>   If more than one entry has the maximum value,
>   an arbitrary choice is made between the entries having the maximum value.

In practice: the first entry found with maximum value is returned.

Groovy however offers a different collection function that can be used to achieve what you expect - [`Collection.inject(initialValue, closure)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#inject(java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) function. This is an equivalent of popular `fold` function known very well in functional programming paradigm. It starts with some initial value and it iterates a collection and applies a function to every element (this function returns a new value that replaces value passed as initial value) to reduce a list of elements to a single element in a single iteration. `Collection.inject()` javadoc gives a very descriptive example of summing all numbers from a list:

```
assert 0+1+2+3+4 == [1,2,3,4].inject(0) { acc, val -> acc + val }
```

Now let's take a look how we can use this function to achieve expected result. Consider following example:

```
def map2= ['a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c':4]

Tuple2<String, Integer> result = map2.inject(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(null, null)) { Tuple2<String, Integer> tuple, entry ->
    entry.value >= tuple.second ?
            new Tuple2<>(entry.value == tuple.second ? '+1than1' : entry.key, entry.value) :
            tuple
}

assert result.first == '+1than1'
assert result.second == 4
```

Here we start with `new Tuple2<String, Integer>(null, null)` as an initial value - a `Tuple2` represents a pair of two values. In our case it represents a key and the maximum value. The closure checks if current entry value is higher or equal the one we store in the tuple and if this is true it checks if the value is the same as the one we have already found - if this is true it uses `+than1` as a key instead of a key taken from map. Otherwise it simply uses entry key without any modification. When the value is lower then the one we currently store in the tuple, existing tuple gets returned. And finally, we get a tuple where `tuple.first` holds a key and `tuple.second` holds a maximum value.

Of course to make the `inject` part more readable it is worth extracting a data class that represents your expected result and behavior. You can implement a function like `compareAndReplace` there to define specific behavior when another maximum value is found. Something like this:

```
import groovy.transform.Immutable

@Immutable
class Result {
    static Result EMPTY = new Result(null, null)

    String key
    Integer value

    Result compareAndReplace(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry, String key = '+1than1') {
        entry.value >= value ?
                new Result(entry.value == value ? key : entry.key, entry.value) :
                this
    }
}

def map2 = ['a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 4]

Result result = map2.inject(Result.EMPTY) { Result result, entry -> result.compareAndReplace(entry) }

assert result.key == '+1than1'
assert result.value == 4
```

Comment: The problem that I have it is that I am not that close to functional programming and I find your answer hard to read and understand. I will test the inject function more and I will try your answer after that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a one-liner but it's still a little obscure:

```
println map2.groupBy{ it.value }.max{ it.key }.value.with{ it.size() > 1 ? ['+than1': it.values()[0]] : it }
```

I'd probably at least extract out the last Closure:

```
def mergedKey = { it.size() > 1 ? ['+than1': it.values()[0]] : it }
def newMap2 = map2.groupBy{ it.value }.max{ it.key }.value.with(mergedKey)
assert newMap2 == ['+than1': 4]
```